# Best coding practice for implementing (NOT using mediation) multiple ad networks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads

I would like to implement two ad networks in my game: Chartboost and Adlovin. I really only have one place where I display ads in my game, and that's after a game over. What I would like to achieve is to display ads from either of those two networks after a game over, without using mediation. I can think of two ways to do it:

1. use an already-existing method that I have in my game which generates a random number between the ints x and y that are passed to the method. For example, generate a random number between 0 and 1; if it's 0 then show a ChartBoost ad, otherwise show an Applovin ad.
2. I could simply alternate between the 2 networks using a BOOL ivar (if YES, show Chartboost ad and then set the iVar to NO. If no, then show Adlovin ad and then set the iVar to YES).

Neither of these methods seem like the best way to accomplish this. Does anyone have any tips on a better approach to this problem? In an ideal scenario, I would be able to monitor the performance of the two ad networks and then remotely stop showing the poorer performing ad network's ads and just stick to the better network without needing to submit a new binary. Clearly my above two approaches would not allow that in their current forms. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults boolForKey:@"FirstTime1"])
{
    [defaults  setInteger:1 forKey:@"MediationAds"];
    [defaults  setBool:YES  forKey:@"FirstTime1"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

if ([defaults integerForKey:@"MediationAds"] == 1) //show chartboost
{
    [self showInterstitial]; 
    [defaults  setInteger:2 forKey:@"MediationAds"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
else if ([defaults integerForKey:@"MediationAds"] == 2) //show applovin
{
    [defaults  setInteger:1 forKey:@"MediationAds"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [ALInterstitialAd showOver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
}
```

So each time you need to show an ad, they will just appear by order, first time chartboost, next time applovin, then again chartboost, then applovin, so they will just change order each time

Comment: I ended up coming up with a similar solution. Instead of just alternating between the two ad networks, I instead chose to randomly display one after a game over (generate a random number between 0 & 1, if 0 -> show chartboost, if 1 -> show applovin). In order to be able to remotely control whether or not the ads from each network show, I leveraged both ad networks' delegate methods that allow you to check if an ad has been successfully cached. If a cache fails, I have my code setup to assume that that means I have turned off that networks ads and to show the other network's ads.